# how to open folders chronologically?

Tags: windows, batch-file

1. Is there a way to open the folders chronologically?
2. How to open the same folder in 2 windows?

Here is the commands I write, but they open the folders in different order every time, and can't open two windows of the same folder..

```
@echo off
start C:\Users\martins\Documents
start C:\Users\martins\Documents
start C:\Users\martins\Pictures
start E:\Downloads
```

Comment: What happens if you use `explorer "c:\users\martins\documents"` etc. instead of `start ...`?

Comment: If chronologically means you want to open them in order that they were created or modified, then you can use a `for` loop on a `dir` command sorted by date.

Comment: explorer open the documents in two windows as I want but they are in random order.
I mean in the order they are written in the batch file.

Comment: It's probably just a display timing issue.  Try adding a delay between each one.  `timeout /t 1 >nul`

Answer (score 0):

You can give a try for this example using `Explorer` and `Timeout` :

```bat
@echo off
Mode 50,3 & color 0A
Title How to open folders chronologically ?

Set Folders="%userprofile%\Documents\" ^
^ "%userprofile%\Downloads\" "%userprofile%\Pictures\" ^
^ "%ProgramData%" "%AppData%" "%LocalAppData%" 

@For %%a in (%Folders%) do ( Call :Explorer %%a 2 )

TimeOut /T 2 /NoBreak>Nul & Exit
::-----------------------
:Explorer <Folder> <Delay>
Cls
echo( 
echo        Opening %1
Explorer %1
TimeOut /T %2 /NoBreak>Nul
Exit /B
::-----------------------
```